# Is it okay to apply filters on database using shared prefs?

Tags: flutter, filter

Currently I am applying my filters on my database using the shared prefs. I got this from one of the tutorials. Is it okay to do it this way, or is there another way to do it. I am thinking this can be done with providers too, but I am not able to wrap my head around implementing it.

Comment: Can you elaborate "applying filters on my database" ? Is it about querying a local front end db ?

Comment: Yes. I am retrieving data from firestore and I am saving it in a local List variable after which I am applying filters on them. Currently I am using shared preference to apply filters on them.